# divide values in a Group By query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by

How is it possible to build a request like this (Sql Server 2008 R2) :
(I need an "Average Price" per result)

```
SELECT 
    CategoryId
  , SUM(Price) AS TotalPrice
  , SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantity
  -->, TotalPrice/TotalQuantity AS AveragePrice
FROM Products 
GROUP BY CategoryId
```

(if possible without recalculating one more times the two SUMs...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

without recalculating...

```
SELECT *, A.TotalPrice / A.TotalQuantity AS AveragePrice
FROM (SELECT 
       CategoryId
       , SUM(Price) AS TotalPrice
       , SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantity
      FROM Products 
      GROUP BY CategoryId) AS A
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  CategoryId, 
        SUM(Price) AS TotalPrice, 
        SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantity, 
        (SUM(Price) * 1.0 / SUM(Quantity) * 1.0) AS AveragePrice
FROM    Products 
GROUP   BY CategoryId
```

or you can use `CTE`

```
WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT  CategoryId, 
            SUM(Price) AS TotalPrice, 
            SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQuantity
    FROM    Products 
    GROUP   BY CategoryId
)
SELECT CategoryId,
       TotalPrice,
       TotalQuantity,
       TotalPrice / TotalQuantity * 1.0 AveragePrice
FROM   cte
```

Comment: try to look at the execution plan.

Comment: Why are you multiplying with 1.0?